# ChartJS - Injecting data from the server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am using in my node app `chartJS 2.7.1`.

My pug file looks like the following:

```
extends layouts/_layout.pug

block content
  .page-title
    div
      h1
        i.fa.fa-dashboard
        |  Bitcoin Price Example

  .row

    .col-md-12
      .card
        h3.card-title Loading local bitcoin file
          canvas#canvas.chartjs-render-monitor(style='display: block; width: 1000px; height: 500px;', width='1000', height='500')      
          console.log(data)

block specific-js
  script(type='text/javascript', src="js/chartJS_price.js") 
  script(type='text/javascript', src="js/plugins/chart.js") // The Chart JS library
```

The `chartJS_price.js` file looks like the following:

```
const lineChartData = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Price",
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    fill: false,
    data: [
            5,
            6
    ],
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
  }, {
    label: "MarketCap",
    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    fill: false,
    data: [
                1,
                3
    ],
    yAxisID: "y-axis-2"
  }]
};
window.onload = function () {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      hoverMode: 'index',
      stacked: false,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Bitcoin Price and MarketCap'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
          display: true,
          position: "left",
          id: "y-axis-1",
        }, {
          type: "linear", // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
          display: true,
          position: "right",
          id: "y-axis-2",
          // grid line settings
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
          },
        }],
      }
    }
  });
};
```

The route in my `app.js` file looks like the following:

```
// routes
app.get('/price', (req, res) => {
    const priceData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './data/prices.json'), 'utf8'))
    res.render('prices', {
        priceData,
      })
})
```

As you can see I am loading the `price` data in the `route` and pass it to the `view`. I am loading the script in my `pug` file with my custom `chartjs` specifications.

Any suggestions how to inject my `priceData` variable from my route into the in the pug-template loaded `chartJS_price.js`.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pug file is fine, you only have to make some changes to your `chart_price.js` file, make a request to the server via ajax, and in your server file, instead of rendering the file, read the file content and use
`res.send(//your json data)`.